# Logstash filter out values with null values for a key in a nested json array

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I have quite an extensive Logstash pipeline ending in a Json as such:

```
{
    "keyA": 1,
    "keyB": "sample",
    "arrayKey": [
        {
            "key": "data"
        },
        {
            "key": null
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to filter `"arrayKey"` and remove objects within with value for `"key"` is `null`.

Tried this to no luck:

```
filter {
    ruby {
      code => "
        event.get('arrayKey').each do |key|
          [key].delete_if do |keyCandidate|
            if [keyCandidate][key] != nil
              true
            end
          end
        end
      "
    }
}
```

This gives no implicit converter found from |hash|:|Int| error. How do I achieve this? Is there and easier way to do this?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Isn't `"key"` required?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread how the data is organized. This should do: `event.get('arrayKey').reject { |h| h["key"].nil? }`

Comment: This didn't help. Should I maybe set the property of the `event`? I still have the null values.

Comment: Try `event.get('arrayKey').reject { |h| h["key"] == "null" }`. I am not familiar with [tag:logstash] syntax, but this way is surely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aleksei pointed out, you can create a copy of the array that does not contain entries where [key] is null using reject. You have to use event.set to overwrite the inital value of [arrayKey]

```
    ruby {
        code => '
            a = event.get("arrayKey")
            if a
                event.set("arrayKey", a.reject { |x| x["key"] == nil })
            end
        '
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Code-only answers can often be difficult to interpret.